# Apply a javascript library on new inserted elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, binding

My code uses "[Datatable](http://datatables.net)" library. 
To initialize a data table on a `<table>` element

```
jQuery_3_3_1(".subtable").DataTable({ });
```

How do I apply this on newly generated elements? (that wont require me to re-render the page or create separate ids for each and initialize different tables).

Edit: I tried this:

```
    jQuery_3_3_1('#readiness').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        alert("potato");
        jQuery_3_3_1(".readiness_subtable").DataTable({ });
    });
```

But still is recalled and Datatable outputs this error msg:

> DataTables warning: table id=readiness_subtable_0
>   - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

when creating more than one "subtable"

Comment: So you are dynamically creating tables and would like to then run the DataTable initialization on them?

Comment: @PhillipThomas yes.

Comment: did you try `jQuery_3_3_1("#newTableId").DataTable({ });`?

Comment: I don't want to initialize it per id. 
I want to set 1 class and all dynamically generated classes will have the same "Datatable" applied on them.

Comment: @PhillipThomas See post update

Comment: Oh, I see. You will have multiple tables then you would like to initialize Datatables across all of them?

Comment: @PhillipThomas yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is from attempting to reinitialize a datatable with **new / custom** options. Ensure you only initialize the table once or do not alter the options passed to the `.DataTable()`, see this example:

```js
let tableData = `<table class="tablesToMakeAwesome">
    <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
              <td>System Architect</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>61</td>
              <td>2011/04/25</td>
              <td>$320,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Garrett Winters</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>63</td>
              <td>2011/07/25</td>
              <td>$170,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Ashton Cox</td>
              <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
              <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>66</td>
              <td>2009/01/12</td>
              <td>$86,000</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>`;
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#test').append(tableData);
  $('.tablesToMakeAwesome').DataTable();
} );

function createTableWorking() {
  $('#test').append(tableData);
  $('.tablesToMakeAwesome').DataTable();
}

function createTableBreaking() {
  $('#test').append(tableData);
  // Cannot pass custom options to already initialized tables.
  $('.tablesToMakeAwesome').DataTable({ });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button onclick="createTableWorking()">Generate Table</button>
<button onclick="createTableBreaking()">Break Tables</button>
<div id="test">
  
</div>
```

I would suggest only initializing a table when it is created and rendered on the DOM. This will allow you to provide it specific table options as well as prevent reinitializing tables that might error out with custom options. Something like:

```js
function createTable() {
    let tableId = (new Date()).getMilliseconds();
    $('#test').append(`
      <table id="${tableId}">
          <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>`);

    $('#' + tableId).DataTable();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button onclick="createTable()">Generate Table</button>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the proper way? Setting dynamic elements and assigning each to Datatable?  Why wouldn't i use a default class to apply to all dynamic elements?

Comment: I would encourage this method assuming you are adding one new table at a time. You will want to initialize it as soon as it renders and not attempt to render all tables as you will have to incorporate logic to prevent reinitializing tables that have already been initialized.

If you are creating several tables at once and would like to initialize them all at once that is possible too. Updating the answer for that.

Comment: @RickSanchez Does this answer your question?

Comment: In a way, yes, i wrote it differently, but I kept using ids. just looked for a different solution with classes. But since it's not a good practice in my case, i used ids as you recommended.